# Поиск в Store ExtJs с использованием фильтров (по ID записей)

Tags: javascript, extjs

Здравствуйте!
Не могу разобраться с поисков в **Store** (**ExtJS 4.1**)...
Есть такая вот ***Store*** (набор полей в примере упрощен). 
(делал по примеру *Ext.data.writer.Writer Example*):

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    idProperty: 'id',
    remoteFilter: true,
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'date', type: 'date' },
        { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'alias', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'text', type: 'string' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: Const.PathDir + 'view/store.html',
            create: Const.PathDir + 'create/store.html',
            update: Const.PathDir + 'update/store.html',
            destroy: Const.PathDir + 'destroy/store.html'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'd',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: false,
            root: 'd'
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                    msg: operation.getError(),
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Из этой Stote нужен всего один элемент с заданным ID. Ищу так

```
activeRecord = store.findRecord('id', itemId);
```

Сервер отдает данные порциями по умолчанию - то есть по 25 элементов. И поиск выполняется только в полученной порции. Все элементы грузить нет резона - объем данных мегабайт на 5 и будет только расти. Пробовал использовать фильтр

```
store.filter([{property: 'id' , value: itemId}]);
activeRecord = store.findRecord('id', itemId);
```

Но так как данные грузятся асинхронно то поиск выполняется по не отфильтрованными данным.

Так вот хотел бы спросить:
Можно ли выполнить поиск на стороне сервера или как-то определить момент загрузки данных с сервера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте функцию [load](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load) или loadRecords для загрузки только нужных записей. [Тут пример](http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.ru/2012/01/how-to-load-single-record-into-store.html).

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно то что нужно...  
Не подскажите ещё как затенить окно?
Скажем переменная **modalWin** - это то окно которое нужно затенить, а из *callback* функции **load** убрать затенение...

Comment: Я вообще ни разу не использовал ExtJS, если что :)

Comment: Что же, спасибо и за это :)

Answer (score 1):

Все просто store.filter() - ищет локально то есть по загруженным данным, если нужно с сервака получить нужно у store указать baseParams: {фильтр} и загрузить заного либо store.reload({lastParams:{фильтр}});

> Спасибо, это действительно то что
> нужно... Не подскажите ещё как
> затенить окно? Скажем переменная
> modalWin - это то окно которое нужно
> затенить, а из callback функции load
> убрать затенение...

```
modalWin.getEl().mask('Згрузка');

убрать 
modalWin.getEl().unmask();
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже получил ответ - [Затенение элементов в ExtJS с выводом сообщения 'Loading...'][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/178656/javascript-затенение-элементов-в-extjs-с-выводом-сообщения-loading